# new Ajax.Request to redirect to new jsp fails.

Tags: ajax, glassfish, struts, prototype

I have 2 login pages, login.jsp and loginMobile.jsp. Login.jsp is default login page and configured in web.xml.
On entring login.jsp a javascript method isMobile is called.

WHITHOUT CHANGING the URL, need to forward the request to loginMobile.jsp.

FRAMEWORK : struts1 , AJAX + prototype + GLASSFISH 3.1.2

2 login pages :

login.jsp

```
<script src="scripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    isMobile();
</script>

<html>
<body>
<p> AM IN LOGIN PAGE </p>
</body>
</html>
```

loginMobile.jsp

```
<script src="scripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<html>
<body>
<p> AM IN MOBILE PAGE </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside login.js

```
function isMobile()
{
//check some conditions then call below AJAX
new Ajax.Request('/loginMobile.jsp', { method:'post' });
 }
```

//Complain's FILE NOT FOUND !!
    "C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\GF3\domain1\docroot\loginMobile.jsp" not found

ALSO TRIED

```
function isMobile()
{
//check some conditions then call below AJAX

var athena_login_url =  window.location.href+'/loginMobile.jsp';
new Ajax.Request(athena_login_url, { method:'post' });

}
```

// Just goes to default login.jsp

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you do this in JS after the client has already started rendering? Use a filter or custom request processor--otherwise you'd need to replace a content div with the results of an Ajax call.

Comment: Thank you, Dave.Step 1: JavaScript (Client end) -> checks browsers and other parameter to determine which  jsp page to be activated.
Step 2: Based on the selection in javascriopt new loginMobile.jsp page is loaded 
        otherwise login.jsp is loaded.
  
  login.jsp -> javascript -> check -> loginMobile.jsp/login.jsp
  
  Please suggest where can filter go in.